# How to use same model scheme for different apps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running two different apps on two different ports on my server. They are both very different, but they use the same mongodb. For every collection there is a different Mongoose model. If one model changes, I do not want to change its scheme in every app using that model.

**Is it possible to store model schemes within the mongodb itself so I only need to create a scheme once and every app is using the same one?**

Comment: Why not store your mongoose schemas themself in a collection in your database?

Comment: Why not put your mongoose schemas into a library which is shared by your applications?

Comment: 1.) How do I store schemas in a collection itself? I have some rather complicated functions attached to some of those. 2.) How would you implement a shared library using schemes?

Comment: Why not just share the code for schema definitions across the two apps? That would be the simplest solution (and most accurate). While you could store source code in a collection, I don't understand why you'd need/want to do that.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Thats sounds legit. And it is no problem, when the apps are running on the same server. But what if the two apps were running on two different servers with the mongodb running on a third?

Comment: Just copy the code? Node.JS is just javascript. I don't understand why both of the apps can't just have a copy?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: The answer is easy: What if I have 100 apps that are all using the same scheme and I want to change the scheme? Don´t you think it is kind of exhausting changing it in every of the app´s code?

Comment: No. It's just source control. Build your own package. You're looking for something that already exists in reasonable ways.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn´t I still have to update every single app or am I missing something here?